# Char pointers and the printf function

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I was trying to learn pointers and I wrote the following code to print the value of the pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        char *p = "abc";
        printf("%c",*p);
        return 0;
    }
```

The output is:

> a

however, if I change the above code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *p = "abc";
    printf(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

> abc

I don't understand the following 2 things:

1. why did printf not require a format specifier in the second case? Is `printf(pointer_name)` enough to print the value of the pointer?
2. as per my understanding (which is very little), *p points to a contiguous block of memory that contains `abc`. I expected both outputs to be the same, i.e.

> abc

are the different outputs because of the different ways of printing?

**Edit 1**

Additionally, the following code produces a runtime error. Why so?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        char *p = "abc";
        printf(*p);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "*`*p` points to a contiguous block of memory*" it points nowhere, as `*p` isn't a pointer but evaluates to a `char`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For your first question, the [`printf` function (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) takes a string as first argument (i.e. a `const char *`). That string could contain format codes that the `printf` function will replace with the corresponding argument. The rest of the text is printed as-is, verbatim. And that's what is happening when you pass `p` as the first argument.

Do note that using `printf` this way is highly unrecommended, especially if the string is contains input from a user. If the user adds formatting codes in the string, and you don't provide the correct arguments then you will have *undefined behavior*. It could even lead to security holes.

For your second question, the variable `p` points to some memory. The expression `*p` dereferences the pointer to give you a single character, namely the one that `p` is actually pointing to, which is `p[0]`.

Think of `p` like this:

```
+---+      +-----+-----+-----+------+
| p | ---> | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | '\0' |
+---+      +-----+-----+-----+------+
```

The variable `p` doesn't really point to a "string", it only points to some single location in memory, namely the first character in the string `"abc"`. It's the functions using `p` that treat that memory as a sequence of characters.

Furthermore, constant string literals are actually stored as (read-only) arrays of the number of character in the string plus one for the string terminator.

Also, to help you understand why `*p` is the same as `p[0]` you need to know that for any pointer *or array* `p` and valid index `i`, the expressions `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)`. To get the first character, you have index `0`, which means you have `p[0]` which then should be equal to `*(p + 0)`. Adding zero to anything is a no-op, so `*(p + 0)` is the same as `*(p)` which is the same as `*p`. Therefore `p[0]` is equal to `*p`.

---

Regarding your edit (where you do `printf(*p)`), since `*p` returns the value of the first "element"  pointed to by `p` (i.e. `p[0]`) you are passing a *single character* as the pointer to the format string. This will lead the compiler to convert it to a pointer which is pointing to whatever address has the value of that single character (it doesn't convert the character to a pointer *to* the character). This address is not a very valid address (in the [ASCII alphabet](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) `'a'` has the value `97` which is the address where the program will look for the string to print) and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: pointer to the format string? won't `p[0]` be treated as the format string itself?

Comment: @simrandhamija: "*`p[0]`*" isn't a "string" but a character, just one `char`. There is a difference between `'A'` and `"A"`. The former is a `char`-literal, the latter is a "string"-literal, which in fact is a '0'-terminated array of `char`.

Answer (score 13):

1. `p` is the format string.

   ```
   char *p = "abc";
   printf(p);
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   print("abc");
   ```

   Doing this is very bad practice because you don't know what the variable
   will contain, and if it contains format specifiers, calling `printf` may do very bad things.
2. The reason why the first case (with `"%c"`) only printed the first character
   is that `%c` means a byte and `*p` means the (first) value which `p` is pointing at.

   `%s` would print the entire string.

   ```
   char *p = "abc";
   printf(p); /* If p is untrusted, bad things will happen, otherwise the string p is written. */
   printf("%c", *p); /* print the first byte in the string p */
   printf("%s", p); /* print the string p */
   ```

Comment: "*means a byte*" is means a `char`, a character will be printed out.

Comment: The word "character" is ambiguous, is it a unsigned integer with a width of at least 8 bits or is it a (possibly encoded) Unicode code point.   Ex. "å" in UTF-8 is one character/letter and two characters/bytes.

Comment: Correcting myself: a `char` in C can be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: If p was instead `const char *p` would the same still apply?

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding, indeed when you do

```
char *p = "Hello";
```

`p` points to the starting address where literal "Hello" is stored. This is how you **declare** pointers. However, when afterwards, you do

```
*p
```

it means **dereference** `p` and obtain object where `p` points. In our above example this would yield 'H'. This should clarify your second question.

In case of printf just try

```
printf("Hello");
```

which is also fine; this answers your first question because it is effectively the same what you did when passed just `p` to printf.

---

Finally to your edit, indeed

```
printf(*p);
```

above line is not correct since printf expects `const char *` and by using `*p` you are passing it a `char` - or in other words 'H' assuming our example. Read more what dereferencing means.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. why did printf not require a format specifier in the second case? Is printf(pointer_name) enough to print the value of the pointer?

"abc" *is* your format specifier.  That's why it's printing "abc".  If the string had contained `%`, then things would have behaved strangely, but they didn't.

```
printf("abc"); // Perfectly fine!
```

> 2. why did printf not require a format specifier in the second case? Is printf(pointer_name) enough to print the value of the pointer?

`%c` is the character conversion specifier.  It instructs `printf` to only print the first byte.  If you want it to print the string, use...

```
printf ("%s", p);
```

The `%s` seems redundant, but it can be useful for printing control characters or if you use width specifiers.

---

The best way to understand this really is to try and print the string `abc%def` using `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

> why did printf not require a format specifier in the second case? Is printf(pointer_name) enough to print the value of the pointer?

With your code you told printf to use your string as the format string. Meaning your code turned equivalent to `printf("abc")`.

> as per my understanding (which is very little), *p points to a contiguous block of memory that contains abc. I expected both outputs to be the same

If you use `%c` you get a character printed, if you use `%s` you get a whole string. But if you tell printf to use the string as the format string, then it will do that too.

`char *p = "abc";
    printf(*p);`

This code crashes because the contents of `p`, the character `'a'` is not a pointer to a format string, it is not even a pointer. That code should not even compile without warnings.

Comment: @simrandhamija Given `printf("%d", 1)`, the `"%d"` is the format string.

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` format specifier expects a `char` type, and will output a *single* `char` value.

The first parameter to `printf` must be a `const char*` (a `char*` can convert implicitly to a `const char*`) and points to the *start* of a *string* of characters. It stops printing when it encounters a `\0` in that string. If there is not a `\0` present in that string then the behaviour of that function is *undefined*. Because `"abc"` doesn't contain any format specifiers, you don't pass any additional arguments to `printf` in that case.