# How do I loop over a char pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to access all elements of this preinitialized `char` pointer in 'c'. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char **s="Hello";
    printf("%c",*(*&s+1));
}
```

This code should output "e", but doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, how do I access all elements one by one?

Comment: I want to access all elements one by one.

Comment: Does this compile? Without warnings? And please edit and add a question. You’ve now only included a mention what you’re trying to do but not what’s wrong. Or what this “e” is

Comment: This gives me more warnings that there are lines of code. Here's a tip: if you want to print all chars of `"Hello"` individually with the `%c` specifier, you'll need a loop.

Comment: Always use your compiler's warnings and head them. With `gcc`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. This would have found the problem.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No, it is giving warning like warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   char **s="Hello";

Answer (score 3):

The type of `s` is incorrect.  The string constant `"Hello"` has array type which can decay to type `char *` but you're assigning it to a variable of type `char **`.

Change the type of `s` to `char *` and your code will output "e":

```
 char *s = "Hello";
```

Also, looking at this:

```
*(*&s+1)
```

When `*` comes right before `&` they cancel each other out.  So you can simplify this to:

```
*(s+1)
```

Or equivalently:

```
s[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you are not seeing the 'e' of the Hello, I highly recommend watching this post.

[What to do when the pointer doesn't print the string properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002185/char-pointers-and-the-printf-function)

Just to summarize, when you reference the pointer s, it is only reading the H of Hello (since that is how the pointer of string works - it points to the first character of the string, like s[0]), and that results your code in printing out H only.

Most importantly, your pointer is double-pointer, which is incorrect.

Try it in this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
  char s[] = "Hello";
  printf("%s\n",s);
}
```